# Pipeline error when referencing C#-defined struct from within PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following `struct` and `class` as part of a PS script module. This part of the code is written in C# and handles code to run when the module is imported into a PowerShell session, though the `OnImport()` bits I haven't included here. This isn't everything the C# code does, just enough to exhibit the issue I'm facing:

```
Add-Type -IgnoreWarnings @"
  using System;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Management.Automation;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
  using System.Runtime.Versioning;

  namespace MyPowerShell {
    public struct State {
      public readonly static ICertificatePolicy OriginalSystemCertificatePolicy = ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy;
      public readonly static ICertificatePolicy SkipSSLCheckPolicy;
      public readonly static Version PSVersion;
      public readonly static string Framework;

      static State() {
        PSVersion = new Version(
          $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major),
          $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor),
          $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Build),
          $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Revision)
        );
        OriginalSystemCertificatePolicy = ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy;
        SkipSSLCheckPolicy = new TrustAllCertsPolicy();
      }
    }

    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
      public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
"@
```

This works fine, and I can reference the `struct` properties and `class` fine from PowerShell once `Add-Type` completes:

```
# Each of these returns the information expected and I can instantiate TrustAllCertsPolicy
[MyPowerShell.State]::PSVersion
[MyPowerShell.State]::OriginalSystemCertificatePolicy
[MyPowerShell.State]::SkipSSLCheckPolicy
$policy = [MyPowerShell.TrustAllCertsPolicy]::new()
```

But I tried adding in a different way to detect the current PowerShell version from within the code that doesn't rely on expanding the `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` properties in the source's `here string`, modifying the `struct` definition a bit:

```
public struct State {
  public readonly static ICertificatePolicy OriginalSystemCertificatePolicy = ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy;
  public readonly static ICertificatePolicy SkipSSLCheckPolicy;
  public readonly static Version PSVersion;
  public readonly static string Framework; # Added this line

  static State() {
    PSVersion = new Version(
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major),
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor),
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Build),
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Revision)
    );
    OriginalSystemCertificatePolicy = ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy;
    SkipSSLCheckPolicy = new TrustAllCertsPolicy();

    # Added the following 2 lines
    TargetFrameworkAttribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute)) as TargetFrameworkAttribute;
    Framework = attribute.FrameworkName;
  }

  // TrustAllCertsPolicy Code
}
```

Once I add the code to pull the `FrameworkName` attribute from the entry assembly in the `struct`'s static constructor, it still compiles but I can no longer reference any of the properties on the `struct` all resulting in a pipeline error:

```
[MyPowerShell.State]::PSVersion

An error occurred while creating the pipeline.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

However, I can use the following calls instead to set `Framework`, going with the `AssemblyProductAttribute` instead from the calling assembly and I don't have a problem:

```
static State() {
  PSVersion = new Version(
    $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major),
    $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor),
    $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Build),
    $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Revision)
  );
  OriginalSystemCertificatePolicy = ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy;
  SkipSSLCheckPolicy = new TrustAllCertsPolicy();

  // Replaced the next two lines with this
  AssemblyProductAttribute productAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute)) as AssemblyProductAttribute;
  Framework = productAttr.Product;
}
```

Why does my `struct` become unusable from PowerShell when I attempt to get the `TargetFrameworkAttribute` from the entry assembly, but works fine when obtaining the `AssemblyProductAttribute` from the calling assembly instead?

Comment: `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetEntryAssembly()` returns `null` because `powershell.exe` is a native PE, not a managed assembly

Comment: Fun. Lovely that the error I got was so descriptive. Any idea why this call works fine from PowerShell Core? Is `pwsh.exe` not also an unmanaged assembly?

Comment: Nvm - seems in PS Core the entry assembly is a DLL, not an executable. Guess that explains it.

Comment: If you put that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the underlying exception, you'll find that the cause is a null-reference being passed to `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute()` in the static constructor.

```
PS ~> $Error[0].GetBaseException() |Format-List -Force


Message        : Value cannot be null.
                 Parameter name: element
ParamName      : element
Data           : {}
InnerException :
TargetSite     : System.Attribute[] GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Type,
                 Boolean)
StackTrace     :    at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType,
                 Boolean inherit)
                    at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType,
                 Boolean inherit)
                    at State..cctor()
HelpLink       :
Source         : mscorlib
HResult        : -2147467261
```

The call to `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns `null` because the hosting application is not actually a managed assembly - `powershell.exe` is a native Win32 PE.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to try checking the base exception. Super annoying the real error was buried though.

Comment: FWIW it's still unclear to me why you're trying to offload version checking to C# in a script module - wouldn't `if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 6){ Add-Type $PS5VersionOfState }else{ Add-Type $PSCoreVersionOfState }` in the root module or a script be easier?

Comment: I'm experienced with scripts, but this is my first PS module I've done. I realized about 30 minutes ago I'm approaching this the wrong way. I don't need to offload anything to C# aside from one class definition, which I may be able to do with a PowerShell class instead.